# Populate Struct of Char Pointers

Tags: c++

Let's say you have this structure:

```
struct MMFS_IDENTIFICATION
{
    char *szVendor;
    char *szControllerModel;
    char *szRevision;
    char *szId;
    char *szExecutive;
    char *szKarelRevision;
    char *szProcessName;
    char *szCommRevision;
    char *szRobotModel;
};
```

Is there any easy way to do something like this?

```
MMFS_IDENTIFICATION mmfsId;

for( int i = 0; i < 9; i++ )
{
    int len = buf[pos++];
    mmfsId[i] = malloc(len);
    memcpy( mmfsId[i], buf[pos], len );
    pos += len;
}
```

The only thing I know to do is copy and paste the code nine times. But I really don't want to do that because in the real program I'm using this concept for, calculating **len** is not as simple as I made it in this example.

Comment: Why are you using `char *` in C++? would `std::strings` be better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since all of the structure members are `char*` pointers, you could do something like this:

```
#include <pshpack1.h>
struct MMFS_IDENTIFICATION
{
    char *szVendor;
    char *szControllerModel;
    char *szRevision;
    char *szId;
    char *szExecutive;
    char *szKarelRevision;
    char *szProcessName;
    char *szCommRevision;
    char *szRobotModel;
}; 
#include <poppack.h>

MMFS_IDENTIFICATION mmfsId;
char** pmmfsId = (char**) &mmfsId;

for( int i = 0; i < 9; ++i )
{
    int len = buf[pos++];
    pmmfsId[i] = malloc(len+1);
    memcpy( pmmfsId[i], buf[pos], len );
}
```

Comment: Doesn't this assume that there are no alignment gaps in MMFS_IDENTIFICATION? I think in practice you might be right for `char*`, but I'm not sure it's 100% guaranteed by the standard. Consider the case of `struct { char a; char b; }` vs `char[2];`.

Comment: @Sjoerd: my example is using the `pshpack1.h` header file to force the structure to have byte alignment, thus no gaps between fields.

Comment: @RemyLebeau-TeamB `pshpack1.h` is not a standard header, so it makes your solution non-portable.

Comment: I do know why @RemyLebeau-TeamB included *pshpack1.h* and *poppack.h*, but they are not necessary for the solution to work.

Comment: `pshpack1.h` is a Microsoft header that uses `#pragma pack(push, 1)` or `#pragma pack(1)` depending on compiler capabilities, and `poppack.h` reverses whatever `pshpack.h` did.

Answer (score 2):

Since your structure contains 9 different pointers with different names, the only *standard* way to access them is with 9 different pieces of code. You might try to cheat and rely on the internal representation of the structure, and you might even get away with it, but it isn't advised.

Use a function to turn each piece into a single one-liner.

```
void CopyString(char * & string_ptr, char * buf, int & pos)
{
    int len = buf[pos++];
    string_ptr = new char[len];
    memcpy( string_ptr, buf[pos], len );
    pos += len;
}

CopyString(mmfsId.szVendor, buf, pos);
CopyString(mmfsId.szControllerModel, buf, pos);
CopyString(mmfsId.szRevision, buf, pos);
CopyString(mmfsId.szId, buf, pos);
CopyString(mmfsId.szExecutive, buf, pos);
CopyString(mmfsId.szKarelRevision, buf, pos);
CopyString(mmfsId.szProcessName, buf, pos);
CopyString(mmfsId.szCommRevision, buf, pos);
CopyString(mmfsId.szRobotModel, buf, pos);
```

Answer (score 0):

For the moment, I've made the members `std::string` instead of `char *`, for the sake of slightly simpler demo code, but the general idea should work the same with with `char *` instead<sup>1</sup>.

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <sstream>

struct MMFS_IDENTIFICATION
{
    std::string Vendor;
    std::string ControllerModel;
    std::string Revision;
    std::string Id;
    std::string Executive;
    std::string KarelRevision;
    std::string ProcessName;
    std::string CommRevision;
    std::string RobotModel;
};

int main() { 
    MMFS_IDENTIFICATION s;

    // We need a char *, because we need to add byte-wise offsets:
    char *base = (char *)&s;

    typedef std::string *ptr;
    ptr fields[9];

    // Set up our `fields` array with the addresses of the fields.
    // Note the parens to force pointer arithmetic on `char *`, *then* conversion 
    // to `std::string *`.
    fields[0] = (std::string *)(base + offsetof(MMFS_IDENTIFICATION, Vendor));
    fields[1] = (std::string *)(base + offsetof(MMFS_IDENTIFICATION, ControllerModel));
    fields[2] = (std::string *)(base + offsetof(MMFS_IDENTIFICATION, Revision));
    fields[3] = (std::string *)(base + offsetof(MMFS_IDENTIFICATION, Id));
    fields[4] = (std::string *)(base + offsetof(MMFS_IDENTIFICATION, Executive));
    fields[5] = (std::string *)(base + offsetof(MMFS_IDENTIFICATION, KarelRevision));
    fields[6] = (std::string *)(base + offsetof(MMFS_IDENTIFICATION, ProcessName));
    fields[7] = (std::string *)(base + offsetof(MMFS_IDENTIFICATION, CommRevision));
    fields[8] = (std::string *)(base + offsetof(MMFS_IDENTIFICATION, RobotModel));

    // Initialize the field contents to some recognizable values:
    for (int i=0; i<9; i++) {
        std::ostringstream buffer;
        buffer << "Field " << i;
        *fields[i] = buffer.str();
    }

    // print out some spot results to show we've written to the fields in the struct:
    std::cout << "printing by field names:\n";
    std::cout << "Vendor = " << s.Vendor << "\n";
    std::cout << "Id = " << s.Id << "\n";
    std::cout << "CommRevision = " << s.CommRevision << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Another possibility would be to use std/tr1/boost tuples. These won't let you use run-time iteration like I have above, but they will give you access to fields by number at compile time. With some case, you can probably use this to eliminate duplication at the source code level, even though it may remain in the object code.

---

1. Technically, you can only use `offsetof` in a POD struct (at least under C++98/03), so it's not required to work at all with them being `std::string`. At least with most typical compilers (e.g., VC++, g++) I've yet to see it fail for non-POD types, at least as long as the parent struct has no virtual functions, etc., of its own.

---